# Add an item to an eloquent collection?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I get all my data like so:

```
$data = Model::all();
```

This returns a collection.

How can I add another parameter to this collection, so for example the data from the model sits under `items` and we have a new param for a piece of data called `max_id`.

Something like:

```
items => all items are here from the `all` call
max_id => 99
```

Comment: Does it work `$data->push(['max_id' => 90]);`

Comment: @sta that just adds it to the eloquent collection

Comment: so you want to add a property to the Collection? could you elaborate a lil about why you want the collection to carry this information? you can have models use an extended collection class if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it like this:

```
$data = [
    'items' => Model::all(),
    'max_id' => 99,
];
```